# Как сделать скрин скриптом powershell?

Tags: powershell

Хочу создать скрипт, что бы удаленно снимать скрин с тачки внутри сети.
Нашел пример по созданию скрина на рабочий стол.

```
$size = [Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen
$bitmap = new-object Drawing.Bitmap $size.width, $size.height
$graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bitmap)
$graphics.CopyFromScreen($size.location,[Drawing.Point]::Empty, $size.size)
$graphics.Dispose()
$bitmap.Save(".\screenshot.jpg")
$bitmap.Dispose()
```

Далее надо это организовать так, что бы я мог делать это удаленно.
Нашел статью по Удаленное взаимодействие с Windows PowerShell без настройки

Добавил

```
$pcname = Read-host "Имя ПК или его IP адрес"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcname -ScriptBlock {
```

Ошибка, нет доступа к тачкам.

Как сделать это из под учетки пользователя или моей?

Comment: если реализовывать это **только** встроенными средствами , можно создать интерактивное задание (task) планировщиком, запускаемое от нужного пользователя.Интерактивное - это значит, что задача не должна быть скрытой. А уж удаленный запуск задания - это простая задача.

Comment: Но как именно это реализовать, если это простая задача. Так как я пока что тычусь в ошибку доступа.

Comment: Надеюсь, понятно, как создать задачу. А вот выполнить удаленно эту задачу средствами планироващика пример:     **SCHTASKS /Run /S <система> /U <пользователь> /P <пароль> /I**. Как выполнить команду на удаленном компьютере через Powershell Вы тоже знаете. Также следует знать, как разрешить [удаленное исполнение](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/ff700227(v=msdn.10)) команд Powershell.